# Graphical lasso implementation with independent regularization per variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, covariance, lasso-regression, covariance-matrix

I'm currently looking for a **graphical lasso implementation** allowing to specify different amount of regularization per variable.

As precised in the [original publication](https://tibshirani.su.domains/ftp/graph.pdf) *(End of page 6, Remark ; also joint image)*, it can make sense to have a regularization that is different for each pair of features.

I know an R implementation allowing to pass the **rho (penalizing parameter)** as a float OR **an array** (features * features), but I couldn't find a matching one in R.

The implementation of [graphical lasso in sklean](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.graphical_lasso.html) doesn't seem to allow such an option since the **penalizing parameter (alpha) should be a float**.

Do you know a way to use this implementation tha way I would need to, or an other package containing such a flexible implementation ?

Thansk a lot for you help ! 
Rémi